# Python socket starts a new socket server

Tags: python, sockets, python-sockets

i was trying to make a chat in Python using Socket and I wanted to make something like a broadcast command with this code:

```
from chatServer import broadcast # The file with definied the broadcast function

def sendBroadcast():
    broadcastVar = input("Send: ")
    broadcast(broadcastVar)
    print("Sended", broadcastVar)

sendBroadcast()
```

And then, while the server script was running (of course it was running), I started the broadcast script. And this error appeared:

```
Host: 192.168.1.109
Port: 42976
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\gp_ga\OneDrive\Documenti\chat\server\broadcast.py", line 2, in <module>
    from chatServer import broadcast
  File "c:\Users\gp_ga\OneDrive\Documenti\chat\server\chatServer.py", line 11, in <module>
    server.bind((host, port))
OSError: [WinError 10048] Normally is allowed one use of every socket address (protocol/address/port)
```

And here is the full code of chatServer.py (I'm italian so go on Google and translate.):

```
import threading
import socket

host = "192.168.1.109"
port = 42976

print(f'''Host: {host}
Porta: {port}''')

server = socket.socket()
server.bind((host, port))
server.listen()

clients = []
nicknames = []

def broadcast(message):
    for client in clients:
        client.send(message)

def handle(client):
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024)
            broadcast(message)
        except:
            index = clients.index(client)

            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()

            nickname = nicknames[index]

            broadcast('{} ha abbandonato!'.format(nickname).encode('utf-8'))
            print(f"{nickname} ha abbandonato.")

            nicknames.remove(nickname)
            break

def receive():
    while True:
        client, address = server.accept()
        print("Connesso con {}".format(str(address)))

        client.send('NICK'.encode('utf-8'))
        nickname = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        nicknames.append(nickname)
        clients.append(client)

        print("Il nickname è {}".format(nickname))
        if nickname == "Admin":
            broadcast("Il capo è entrato! Salutate l'Admin!".encode('utf-8'))
        else:
            broadcast("{} è entrato!".format(nickname).encode('utf-8'))
        client.send('Connesso al server!'.encode('utf-8'))

        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(client,))
        thread.start()

receive()
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: what is the broadcast function?

Comment: @user253751 here is the broadcast function from chatServer.py:
`
def broadcast(message):
    for client in clients:
        client.send(message)
`

Comment: So you have two different programs and both of the programs do `server.bind((host, port))`?

Comment: Yes, in the fileone where the sendBroadcast() function is defined I never told to start another server.

Comment: You did, though. `from chatServer import` runs all the code in chatServer.py

Comment: So what can I do?

Comment: don't make more than one program bind to the same port